# How to import .XEL files into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, azure-sql-database, extended-events

I need to investigate some events from Azure SQL Database.

The Audit logs were stored on a Storage Account and I have downloaded them on my laptop. They are now all in the same folder.

There are many guides that explains you how to import such files into SQL Server:

- https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/01/query-extended-events-target-xml/
- https://gist.github.com/brazilnut2000/f9e9859f095219b1a17d151292efc278
- https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/reading-from-extended-events-xml-column-event_data
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226704/how-to-view-xevent-event-file-data

But when I try to run the query

```
SELECT event_data = convert(XML, event_data)
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'C:\Users\FrancescoMantovani\Downloads\Investigate\*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I receive the error:

> Msg 25718, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
> The log file name "C:\Users\FrancescoMantovani\Downloads\Investigate*.xel" is invalid.  Verify that the file exists and that the SQL Server service account has access to it.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I tried to put the files into the `DATA` folder inside Microsoft SQL Server, the error has now changed. Command:

```
SELECT event_data = convert(XML, event_data)
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Investigate\00_00_06_511_24.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Error:

```
Msg 25748, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
The file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Investigate\00_00_06_511_24.xel" contains audit logs. Audit logs can only be accessed by using the fn_get_audit_file function.
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty self-explanatory. Does the account under which SQL Server executes have access to the `C:\Users\FrancescoMantovani\Downloads` folder? If not, can you put the files somewhere that it does, like maybe `C:\Temp`?

Comment: The xel file is not XML (or bad XML).  XML is text so open the file with a text editor and verify that file is XML.  There are online XML checkers that you can use.

Comment: Franceso, try creating a new folder C:\xelfiles. Try adding Windows permissions to "everyone" as "full control". Once you have imported the files you can remove the folder.

Comment: Nice catch. I have updated my question. The error has now changed. Thank you all for your help

Comment: RE: Edit. Seriously? Just read the error messages. Both of the ones you have posted have told you the problem

Comment: use [sys.fn_get_audit_file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to read audit file in sql.

Comment: Thank you @PratikLad but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the audit files were from Azure SQL Database it was easier for me to use a direct connection to the Storage Account [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#azure-sql-database):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs/weu-cust-npr-mssql-srvr/mydatabase/SqlDbAuditing_ServerAudit/2023-07-29/00_00_06_604_12.xel', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
GO
```

And if you want to query the whole folder:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file('https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs/weu-cust-npr-mssql-srvr/mydatabase/SqlDbAuditing_ServerAudit/2023-07-29/', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
GO
```